# Extracting functions from a PDE that may or may not be subscripted

Tags: differential-equations, pattern-matching, filtering, algebraic-manipulation

Using the Mathematica code

```
pde = -Subscript[\[Sigma], 
f] (1 + Subscript[\[Chi], 
 f]) (D[h[x, z], z] D[Subscript[A, SuperPlus[v]][x, y, z], x, y] +
  D[Subscript[A, SuperPlus[v]][x, y, z], x, z] + 
 D[b[x, y, z], z] D[h[x, z], z] - D[b[x, y, z], y] + 
 D[Subscript[B, x][x, y, z], z] D[h[x, z], z] - 
 D[Subscript[B, x][x, y, z], y] + D[Subscript[B, y][x, y, z], x] -
  D[Subscript[B, z][x, y, z], x] D[h[x, z], z]) == 0
```

I obtain the following equation:

$$-\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{y}}-\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{z}}-\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}}+\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{y}}-\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial {B}_x}{\partial \mathit{z}}+\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial {B}_x}{\partial \mathit{y}}-\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial {B}_y}{\partial \mathit{x}}+\sigma _f \left(\chi _f+1\right) \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial {B}_z}{\partial \mathit{x}}=0$$

I have written a function which can extract terms involving the partial derivatives of some specified function. This is given by

```
TermsContainingDerivatives[eqn_, func_] := Total[Cases[Terms[eqn], a_ /; ! FreeQ[a, Derivative[___][func][__]] -> a]][;
```

where `Terms` is given by (*perhaps not the most elegant - please do point out if there is a more elegant way of defining it*):

```
Terms[eqn_] := (ExpandAll@First@SubtractSides@eqn)[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[ExpandAll@First@SubtractSides@eqn]]
```

As expected, the output of `TermsContainingDerivatives[pde,b]` is

$$-\sigma _f \chi _f \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}}-\sigma _f \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}}+\sigma _f \chi _f \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{y}}+\sigma _f \frac{\partial \mathit{b}}{\partial \mathit{y}}$$

When I apply the same to `TermsContainingDerivatives[pde,A]`, it gives 0. However, I would like it to pick up the terms subscripted $v^+$.

If I try to modify the function to become

```
TermsContainingDerivatives[eqn_, func_] := 
  Total[Cases[Terms[eqn], a_ /; ! FreeQ[a, Derivative[___][Subscript[func, __]][__]] -> a]];
```

the result of `TermsContainingDerivatives[pde,A]` then becomes
$$-\sigma _f \chi _f \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{y}}-\sigma _f \frac{\partial \mathit{h}}{\partial \mathit{z}} \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{y}}-\sigma _f \chi _f \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{z}}-\sigma _f \frac{\partial ^2{A}_{v^+}}{\partial \mathit{x}\, \partial \mathit{z}}$$
but then `TermsContainingDerivatives[pde,b]` gives zero.

My question is:

- *How can I modify my function which gives the non-zero answers in both cases, so that terms are picked up regardless of whether they are subscripted or not?*

Furthermore, as a more general question:

- *When constructing a function, is it possible to specify that an input may be empty*?

Comment: Please show us the _Mathematica_ code for `pde`.

Comment: I've added this to the start of the question.

Comment: What is the function `Terms`?

Comment: @DanielHuber Done, but there might be a more elegant way of defining it.

Comment: `TermsContainingDerivatives[pde, b]` gives not zero, but:`(-Subscript[\[Sigma], f])*Derivative[0, 1][h][x, z]*
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, y, z] - 
   Subscript[\[Sigma], f]*Subscript[\[Chi], f]*  Maybe a new kernel will help.
  Derivative[0, 1][h][x, z]*
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, y, z] + 
 Subscript[\[Sigma], f]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][b][x, y, z] + 
   Subscript[\[Sigma], f]*Subscript[\[Chi], f]*
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][b][x, y, z]`  Maybe a new kernel will help.

Comment: Which form of `TermsContainingDerivatives` did you use?

Comment: My mistake, I used the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that works for `A` and `b`:

```
TermsContainingDerivatives[eqn_, func_] := 
 Total[Cases[Terms[eqn], 
   a_ /; (! FreeQ[a, Derivative[___][func][__]] || ! 
        FreeQ[a, Derivative[___][Subscript[func, __]][__]]) -> a]]

TermsContainingDerivatives[pde, A]
```

[image]

```
TermsContainingDerivatives[pde, b]
```

[image]